# How to connect to Heroku postgres db from WSL2?

Tags: heroku, wsl-2, heroku-postgres

I have a flask app running on Heroku with postgres database.

When trying to run the app localy on WSL2, the app runs, but when there is interaction with the db it curshes with the following error:

```
connection to server at "x-x-x-x-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (x.xxx.xxx.169), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "xxxxxx828vkthi
" does not exist
```

(I have replaced the numbers with x)

I have opened port 5432 on windows, but still the same error appear.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

My setup on the flask app is

```
app = Flask(__name__)
DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
DATABASE_URI= DATABASE_URI[:8]+'ql' + DATABASE_URI[8:]
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
db=scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Comment: If you're running locally you won't automatically get the correct `DATABASE_URL`. How are you setting that value on your local machine?

Comment: I have added it as an envrioment variable, but I know that the URL may change. This why I have env file which I currently setting as an enviroment variable before flask run command. The current DATABASE_URL set on the env variable is the same as on the Heroku DATABASE_URL. Apart that I need to run it as postgresql://

Comment: There is a newline in the error message after the database name and before the closing quote. Is that actually present in the error message?

Comment: I managed to fix this by changing the DATABASE_URL on my env variable based on heroku config:get DATABASE_URL + changing it so postgresql:// and changing the setup to: engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db=scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

Comment: I'm not sure how your `db` variable is used, but I suspect the `DATABASE_URL` simply wasn't set correctly before. I believe it included a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

[Nothing should prevent this from working on the Heroku side](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#external-connections-ingress). Just make sure to always use the connection information provided by `DATABASE_URL` (it can change at any time) and to use `sslmode=require`. You can get the current value of the `DATABASE_URL` by running

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
```

Since this is an outbound connection you shouldn't have to open any ports on WSL or Windows. Out of the box, this outbound connection should work.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working following Connecting in Python as mentioned in the link. I get the same issue. I have upadted the question to show my intialization setup on the app that work on Heroku. I can only make it work with DATABASE_URI= DATABASE_URI[:8]+'ql' + DATABASE_URI[8:]
added.